# Google Maps v3 Marker Always Appears at Top Left

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, coffeescript

I'm writing some Google Maps API v3 code, which seems to work just fine with multiple markers, but when there's only 1, it always plots the marker in the top left of the map, just beyond the visible area:

[image: Screenshot of how the map looks]

Here's my coffeescript code:

```
class SimpleMap
    constructor: (div_id, lat = 40.783627, lng = -73.942583) ->
        # L.Icon.Default.imagePath = "/assets"
        @div_id = div_id
        @map_options = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: 10, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}
        @markers = []
        @map = new google.maps.Map document.getElementById(div_id), @map_options
        @loadMarkers() # gets them and plots on the map
        @autoFit()
    loadMarkers: ->
        items = $(".grid-item[data-lat], .apartment[data-lat]")
        for item in items
        console.log "Adding #{item}"
        @addMarker(item)
    @autoFit()

    addMarker: (item) ->
        console.log "Adding marker"
        lat = $(item).attr("data-lat")
        lng = $(item).attr("data-lng")

        console.log "#{lat}, #{lng}"

        marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            position: new google.maps.LatLng lat, lng
            map: @map
            title: "This is my marker"
        )

        @markers.push marker

    autoFit: ->
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds()
        for marker in @markers
            bounds.extend marker.getPosition()
        @map.fitBounds bounds
        # if you leave out the below, the marker appears int he same position as in the screenshot (slightly off screen) but at the max zoom level. 
        listener = google.maps.event.addListener(@map, "idle", =>
            @map.setZoom 9 if @map.getZoom() > 8
            @map.setCenter @markers[0].getPosition()
            google.maps.event.removeListener listener
        )
```

The map seems to ignore my attempts to set `setCenter(@markers[0].getPosition())`. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure your map DIV has a size, (both width and height), before creating the Map object, and that lat and lng are actually numbers and not strings. Use parseFloat(lat) and parseFloat(lng) if necessary.

Comment: what's going on in loadMarkers? If there is network traffic then autofit may be called before your data is loaded.

Comment: I added the code for loadMarkers. In this case I load the markers from the HTML that's on the same page as the map. The map div has styles set explicitly via CSS, also, and I'm creating the markers with LatLngs, not strings -- the markers themselves always appear in their correct places, just the zoom/center problem persists when there is only ONE marker. With multiple markers it displays fine and fits the bounds reasonably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is in:

```
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds()
    for marker in @markers
        bounds.extend marker.getPosition()
    @map.fitBounds bounds
```

where you are extending the current map bounds to include all markers, but you have only one marker, the bounds will extend in a way that the marker will be in the map limit border.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments this issue occurs only when there is 1 marker.

Based on this fact I would neardown the problem to this line:

```
@map.fitBounds bounds
```

When there is only 1 marker, the NE-corner of bounds is equal to the SW-corner.

I noticed unexpected interactions when you use bounds as fitBounds()-argument in this case.

**Suggestion:**

only use fitBounds() when there are at least 2 markers.